# In Java swing, while handling a 2D top down game, how should I handle scaling for quality transformations (mainly screen rotation)

Tags: java, 2d, transformation, swing

For my top down game, I plan to have screen rotation where entities don't rotate, but everything else does. I am using a raster array to store my image so I don't have to render things stacked on each other. I have my game scaled by three, however so pixels are 3 times as large and take up 9 times more space meaning that when I do a matrix rotation for everything except the player and entities, the pixels are very badly rotated as it is rotating then scaling afterwards.

Essentially, I copy whatever pixels I need to to the main image (both arrays of pixels), then after that it is scaled by three and drawn to the actual screen (with the Java `Graphics`). Mainly, I would like to do quality rotations and scaling means that I cannot do that.

Also off a little bit from the question, how would you recommend I handle the rotation so that the entities stay upright and everything except the map moves while keeping collision and logic working fine. Similar to how the game [Realm of the Mad God](http://www.realmofthemadgod.com) works.

I am willing to change my rendering logic a bit, however I want to keep it as efficient as possible. I can also change my game into 3D in order to have higher quality walls and such.

Overall, I am asking:
How should I handle scaling so that I can use high quality transformations and how would I efficiently and effectively implement screen rotation.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should use [Java2D transformations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) for rotating and scaling images. This way you get both [quality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html) and [performance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/perf-graphics-135933.html) in an easy way.

Comment: Should I use multilayer rendering then? I have a pixel arrray which I draw things to, then I scale it to fit the window. I know I could just draw the entities on a separate layer however then performance is hit a little bit.

Comment: Why do you want to draw to a pixel array first? I think you need to provide some pictures to clarify what you are really after.